# contar los elementos de un array de objetos y devolver un objeto

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de contar cuantas veces c repite un elemento dentro de un array de objetos pero necesito retornar un array de arrays con 2 elementos el nombre y la cantidad por ejemplo :

```js
const input = [
  {
    name:'pedro',
    edad:15,
    zapatos:{
      name:"adidas",
      size: 15
    }
  },
  {
    name:'maria',
    edad:15,
    zapatos:{
      name:"adidas",
      size: 15
    }
  },
  {
    name:'jose',
    edad:15,
    zapatos:{
      name:"jordan",
      size: 15
    }
  },
  {
    name:'gabriel',
    edad:15,
    zapatos:{
      name:"jordan",
      size: 15
    }
  },
  {
    name:'roberto',
    edad:15,
    zapatos:{
      name:"adidas",
      size: 15
    }
  },
]
```

```js
const output = [
      ['adidas',3], ['jordan',2],['nike',2]
    ]
```

el codigo que tengo hasta ahora es este

```js
const newObject = input.map( ( elem ) => elem.takeBy.name);

      const counted = newObject.reduce ( ( acc, el) => (
        acc [el] ? acc[el] += 1 : acc[el] = 1 , acc
        )
        ,[]
      );
```

pero lo que esto me retorna es lo siguiente :

```
[ 'adidas': 1, 'jordan': 4, 'nike': 3 ]
```

hasta este punto me quede atorado no se como transformar la informacion con la estructura que necesito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferencia de PHP, en JS los corchetes no sirven para declarar un "array asociativo". Así que:

> pero lo que esto me retorna es lo siguiente :
>
> [ 'adidas': 1, 'jordan': 4, 'nike': 3 ]

Es incorrecto. Lo que te retorna es esto:

```
{ 'adidas': 1, 'jordan': 4, 'nike': 3 }
```

Por lo cual puedes usar `Object.entries` sobre tu objeto, para obtener un array de arrays (se le denomina `entries` a los pares de un objeto)

```js
let result = Object.entries({ 'adidas': 1, 'jordan': 4, 'nike': 3 })
console.log(result)
```

Comment: excelente muchas muchas gracias, me sirvio

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
    {
        name: 'pedro',
        edad: 15,
        zapatos: {
            name: "adidas",
            size: 15
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'maria',
        edad: 15,
        zapatos: {
            name: "adidas",
            size: 15
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'jose',
        edad: 15,
        zapatos: {
            name: "jordan",
            size: 15
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'gabriel',
        edad: 15,
        zapatos: {
            name: "jordan",
            size: 15
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'roberto',
        edad: 15,
        zapatos: {
            name: "nike",
            size: 15
        }
    }
];

//Agrupamos
let agrupacion=input.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
    let groupKey = currentValue.zapatos.name;
   
    if (!acc[groupKey]) {
      acc[groupKey] = [];
    }
    acc[groupKey].push(currentValue);
    return acc;
   }, {});
   
//cambiamos el formato
let resp = Object.keys(agrupacion).map((el) => [el, agrupacion[el].length] );
console.log(resp);
```